# Radius of Convergence of $\sum a_nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Not really sure what I'm missing on this problem: Find the radius of convergence for the following:

$$\sum a_n x^n= \sum \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^2}x^n$$

From my understanding:

$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence. Therefore I get:

$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{((n+1)!)^2}{(3(n+1))!}=\frac{(n+1)}{3}=\infty$$

But the answer is $0$, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some calculational details are not right. When you simplify $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ you should get something like 
$$\dfrac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^2}.$$ 
This is because $(3(n+1))!=(3n+3)!=(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(3n)!$.

But that slip makes no difference here, since the limit is still "$\infty$." The radius of convergence is the "reciprocal" of that, namely $0$.